# Laravel 5.5 : array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a csv which I would like to insert into a database table,I have removed the headers so it can be combined as reference when I use foreach to get the row values. The data does insert into the database table but  an error is thrown saying `both parameters should have an equal number of elements` in the array_combined . I have checked the header array and dd() on a single row and the element numbers are the same. But the error keeps show after I have done the post.

```
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n",$csvData) );
$header = array_shift($rows);

      foreach($rows as $row )
        {
                $row = array_combine($header, $row);
                People::create([
                    'name' => $row['Name'],
                    'surname' => $row['Surname'],
                    'age' => $row['Age'],
                    'sex' => $row['Sex'],
                    'note' => $row['Note'],
                    'list_id' => $list_num
                ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem might be last row.

You can verify what's the exact problem replacing:

```
$row = array_combine($header, $row);
```

with:

```
if (count($header) != count($row)) {
  dd($header, $row);
}
```

And in your case after tracking the problem you can simple skip the row in such case for example like this:

```
if (count($header) != count($row)) {
  continue;
}
```